# MySQL query with JOINs in large Database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table with hundreds of millions of rows.  See create statement below:

```
 CREATE TABLE `transaction_history` (
  `transaction_history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settlement_date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_history_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `transaction_history_id_UNIQUE` (`transaction_history_id`),
  KEY `type_id_idx` (`type_id`),
  KEY `sub_type_id_idx` (`sub_type_id_id`),
  KEY `transaction_id_idx` (`ufmid`),
  KEY `settlement_date` (`settlement_date_time`),
  KEY `type_sub_type` (`type_id`,`sub_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36832823 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Information on the table:
There are multiple settlement_date_times for each transaction_id.
type_id and sub_type_id together are unique

Query that I need to create:
For each transaction_id I need to get the latest settlement date time then count the number of (type_id and sub_type).

So the result would look something like this:

```
(type_id,sub_type_id) -> count 
(3,4) -> 23500
(2,2) -> 569323
(2,3) -> 45028
(3,2) -> 1038943
```

No matter what I do I cannot create a query that runs reasonably fast.  Everything I create times out after 20mins. Is there a way to run this query in a few minutes or seconds?

One of the queries I tried:

```
select count(a1.transaction_id), a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id
from  transaction_history a1, transaction_history a2 
where a1.transaction_id= a2.transaction_id
and  not exists (Select a1.settlement_date_time < a2.settlement_date_time) 
group by a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id
```

Thank you

Comment: "For each transaction_id I need to get the latest settlement date time" -- I'm not seeing the date time in the output. Do you want only the count of (type_id and sub_type_id) on the latest settlement datetime? Do you need to know what that datetime is?

Comment: I don't need the date time, I just need to get the count for the latest date-time... Ty

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
select count(a1.transaction_id), a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id  
from  transaction_history a1 join transaction_history a2 using(transaction_id)
where  a1.settlement_date_time > a2.settlement_date_time 
group by a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id
```

Hope this will help

Comment: If we join on transaction_id, will settlement_date_time ever be different? Would this return results?

Comment: Thank you Faizan for the quick reply.  Unfortunately this query gave me the same results as the other ones I tried.... connection time out.  The issue is that it does not seem to use the key.  From explain it shows that the JOIN uses the key but the group by/count does not (Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery to first find the latest datetime for each pair:

```
select count(hist.transaction_id), hist.type_id, hist.sub_type_id
from  transaction_history hist 
    (select type_id, sub_type_id, max(settlement_date_time) as max_dt 
    from transaction_history group by type_id, sub_type_id) latest_date 
on hist.type_id= latest_date.type_id AND 
 hist.sub_type_id=latest_date.sub_type_id AND 
 hist.settlement_date_time = latest_date.max_dt
group by hist.type_id, hist.sub_type_id
```

The subquery finds the latest datetime for each pair, and then the join finds records from the main table where the pair has the same datetime. Then we can count the transactions.

Comment: Thank you CGritton, even the subquery takes too long to complete where possible_keys is null and ref is null (in mysql explain)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any details of the plans used by your DBMS nor the data distribution.

> For each transaction_id I need to get the latest settlement date time then count the number of (type_id and sub_type).

Do you mean you need to see every type_id and every sub-type, or only the unique combinations? Is this for every row in the table or only the ones which have the latest settlement date for each transaction_id? If the former then your indexes are slowing down the query - a full table scan would be faster. But if you want reasonable response time then you need to denormalize the data.

Your table is badly designed - the index type_id_idx is an overhead which adds no value in the presence of type_sub_type.

Comment: Thank you symcbean: I need only the unique combinations.  Only rows that have the latest settlement date for each transaction ID.

Comment: As for the design.  The index for type_id and sub_type_id are there if they need to be searched for individually not for the current query.  Do you think I should remove both?

Comment: You should *only* ever have indexes which will be used for queries or for enforcing unique constraints. A query with a predicate on type_id can use index sub_type_id even in the absence of a sub_type_id predicate and it will be just as efficient. I suspect the DBMS will ignore  type_id_idx. Certainly type_id_idx should be dropped.

Comment: Your UNIQUE KEY is also redundant since you're using the same attribute in your primary key.

Comment: Drop these 2 indices and add one on (type_id, settlement_date and transaction_id) and rewrite your query around `SELECT type_id, MAX(entitlement_date) FROM transaction_history GROUP BY type_id` as a sub-query.

Comment: Thank you symcbean, I definitely agree with you that the indexes need to be changed.  The 2 indexes you are referring to are type_id_idx and transaction_history_id_UNIQUE but not sub_type_id_idx? I do believe the group by needs to be (type_id, sub_type_id) as this is the value that should be unique

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the suggested queries mentioned above I would like to make two more recommendations that would help you arrive at the most optimized solution:

1)   Take a look at the “**Execution Plan**” of the query.

In MySQL we use the “**EXPLAIN**” command, which makes our calculations a whole lot easier. See this for more details (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)

In MS SQL Server we would do something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to display the execution plan of the query (P.S The shortcut may vary depending on the version). See the following for more details (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/).

2)  If still, we are unable to arrive at a single answer, the easiest thing we can do is to test all proposed / alternate versions of the query by enabling certain profiling tools.

In **MySQL**  we can use the “SHOW PROFILE” command, which works like this;

SET profiling = 1;

.

.

***Our query goes here***

.

.

SHOW PROFILES;

See this for more details (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html)

Alternatively, in **MS SQL** we can set the “STATISTICS” and “TIME” options on, this works as follows:

SET STATISTICS IO ON

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

.

.

***Our query goes here***

.

.

SET STATISTICS IO OFF

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

This would give us the running time/resource usage of our query, in the messages window.

By doing this, we could narrow down the query with the least running time. Hopefully, this would help you at the most optimized query for the task.

Comment: Thank you Mikaal for the reply.  I've been trying the different querys and modifying the indexes but nothing I do seem to work.  I simplified the query a lot in order to get a better understanding of what is going on, but even a simple query with the right indexes doing use the indexes correctly and I don't know why.  see example in my next comment

Comment: select type_id, sub_type_id, max(settlement_date_time) as max_dt 
    from transaction_history group by type_id, sub_type_id

Comment: Result from Explain: 
id -> 1, select_type -> SIMPLE, table -> transaction_history, type -> index, possible keys -> NULL, key -> type_sub_type, key_len -> 9, ref -> null, rows -> 37025337, filtered -> 100.00, Extra -> "blank"

Comment: New indexes:
PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_history_id`),
KEY `sub_type_id_idx` (`sub_type_id_id`),
KEY `settlement_date` (`settlement_date_time`),
KEY `type_sub_type` (`type_id`,`sub_type_id`)

Comment: From the explain I do not understand why the possible keys and the ref are both NULL when it says it's using the correct index

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT count(a1.transaction_id), a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id
FROM (SELECT transaction_id,MAX(settlement_date_time) MAX_settlement_date_time FROM transaction_history GROUP BY transaction_id)maxdts
INNER JOIN transaction_history a1 ON a1.transaction_id= maxdts.transaction_id AND a1.settlement_date_time = maxdts.MAX_settlement_date_time
group by a1.type_id, a1.sub_type_id
```